# Advices on full overlay search menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I started a blog. I'm new to coding and I want to transform my Search menu into a full overlay search menu. But for mobile devices, I only want something like this:

[image: menu]

And I don't really know, should I make a brand new search menu only for mobiles, or edit that one with resizing and other stuff?

I'm working on WordPress, and  I know that there are plugins for this work, but I want to learn how to do it by myself. Not only that, but coding as all. And yea, I know it's bad, but it's my first one! :) So any suggestions would be really appreciated.

My blog link:[www.shreddingnation.com](http://www.shreddingnation.com)

I really don't know which code to paste, and if there is even any need to paste code, so if you want me to paste anything, just say what. THANKS!

Comment: Please review the help center documentation on how to ask good questions. In particular please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to use Css Media Queries. So in this case at a width <= 600px there will be a full search overlay.

1) Add the following css to wp-content/themes/yuuta/style.css

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    .site-header .search-form.search-form--active {
        position: absolute;
        top: 80px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    }
    .site-header .search-form input.search-field {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        color: #000;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
}
```

2) Add the following js to /wp-content/themes/yuuta/assets/js/theme.js

after /* hide search field */ add

```
$('body').css('overflow','auto');
```

and after /* show search field */ add

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden');
```

Hope this helps...